# Reading root element from XML file

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to read a root element from XML file.

```
<Records Heading="Image" Url="images.iteam.com/alpha.png" Val="un-val">
  <Record IdValues="OrdersID=120">
    <Col TableName="" Id="0" Name="Row" Cap="Row" Val="1" Type="" LinkId=""/>
.
.
.
  </Record>
</Record>
```

I have above code and I want to read `Url="images.iteam.com/alpha.png"` value in code. This code is saved in xml file and I am using java language for this.

Comment: What have you tried... There are a variety of ways to skin a cat here you can use a SAX processor but if all you really want is the one item you can use String parsing/searching to solve this issue

Comment: This was so easy I thought.But I can't get element from parent .I able to get the attribute value by using    ParseEvent event = event.getValue("Url"));    but I am facing this exception, class java.lang.RuntimeException, java.lang.RuntimeException: Attribute Url in StartTag <Record> line sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xml parser to parse xml file in java.

1. [DOM XML Parser Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)
2. [SAX Parser Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)

Comment: is there any example that can lead me to use 'kxml'. Because I am using this library at this time.